# catch exception thowns by prototype javascript framework

Tags: javascript, exception, prototypejs, reverse-ajax

I'm using the [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) framework to obtain a reverse ajax effect in my page, i'm using this script:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="prototype.js"></script>
<script>
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
connectToServer();
});

function connectToServer()
{
new Ajax.Updater(
    { success: 'asd', failure: 'error' },
    'evaluation',
    {
        method:     'get',
        onSuccess:  function(transport)
        {
            if (transport.responseText!=''){
                try {
                    eval(transport.responseText)
                } catch (e) {
                    alert(e.message);
                }
            }
            connectToServer();
        },
    });
 }
 </script>
```

The script works correctlty but i have a problem, when i shutdown the web server (in my case a little web server i wrote in python) a lot of exception are thrown due to error 404, is there a way to catch this exception and block the script?

Answer (score 3):

Add an `on404` option to the `Ajax.Updater` options,  pass a function handler like you have done for `onSuccess`.

the `on<HTTPSTATUSCODE>` handler will prevent the onSuccess from firing only if the HTTP code exists as a handler. ie If the webserver responds with a 500 error and you only have a `on404` handler defined, `onSuccess` might still run, but shouldn't because success is defined as any of the 200s status codes.

Comment: ok, now it says only once 'Failed to load Resource', i changed the onSuccess to on200, but how can i catch the 'failed to load event'? for example i want to show a pop up on this event

Comment: I'll check it out - its in the documentation so it "should" work....   You might want to try the `onFailure` handler